# how to implement a combo box matching the last in the autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, wpf-controls

For the auto-complete functionality, it will automatically matching the prefix of the items. 
And focus the first of the filtered items. But i would like to let the combo-box focus on the last items of the filtered items.

For instance, if the dataset are "ABA,ABB,ACC", if i input AB, the ABA and ABB will be filtered, and the focus will be on the ABA(above ABB), now what i want is focus on ABB(below ABA).

I checked that combo-box does have AutoCompleteMode, but none of them seems can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom auto complete source that is different from the combo-box items list. This allows you to specify entries that are sorted in reverse order and to keep the right order for the combo-box items at the same time

```
cb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
var strings = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
strings.AddRange(arrayWithItemsInReverseOrder);
cb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = strings;
```

Comment: apologize that i did say it wrong. I am trying to use wpf. But I also tried to use the WindowsFormHost to use the window.form.combobox, but seems, there is no focus on the filtered items

Comment: Have you also tried to set different AutoCompleteModes (Suggest, Append, 
SuggestAppend)?
`cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append`